# Adding Feature in HGNN to Count Connections to Types of Nodes

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, graph-neural-networks

So I'm making a HGNN currently in which the number of connections a node has to other nodes of a certain type matters. Its a social network, so I care about how many person-person connections a person has, or how many house-person connections a house has. I was wondering whether this sort of information was implicit in a traditional HGNN structure, or whether it has to be added explicitly through features. 
If that is the case, then would it suffice to just add a feature full of 1s to every node type so that when the information is propagated, those are added up, or should I make a more explicit feature that acts as a counter for this?